# Javafx: Dialog y position doesn't work properly

Tags: java, javafx

Please, consider the following code:

```
public class JavaFxTest4 extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setText("dialog");
        button.setOnAction((e) -> {
            Dialog<?> d = new Dialog<>();
            final Window window = d.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
            Stage stage = (Stage) window;
            stage.setMinHeight(450);
            stage.setMaxHeight(450);
            stage.setHeight(450);
            stage.setMinWidth(600);
            stage.setMaxWidth(600);
            stage.setWidth(600);
            window.setY(300); //<---- note this line
            window.setX(660); //<---- note this line
            d.showAndWait();
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(button);
        var scene = new Scene(root, 1920, 1000);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

As you can see window position is 660 (x) and 300 (y). And this is the result:
[image]

[image]

As you can see x position is correct, but y position is not. Is this a bug or I misunderstand something? I use javafx 19-ea+3 and openjdk version "14.0.2" on Ubuntu 20.

Comment: Not that it changes much, but shouldn't you be measuring from the top of the screen?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I've just measured - gnome top bar height is 30px, but dialog measured y is about 200. Gnome doesn't allow programs (kruler) be over top bar.

Comment: Would this approach risk truncating the the dialog's content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in JavaFX. Issue is [here](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8288996)